# PHP, IIS 7, receiving smtp;504 Need Fully Qualified Address

Tags: php, email, iis, smtp

I am using Drupal with IIS7 and PHP to email the results of a form. the user fills out the form, the form is (supposed to be) emailed to me. The script runs without error, but there is no email sent. When I look in the queue folder for the virtual smtp server, there is the following:

```
 Final-Recipient: rfc822;my@email.com *my email is here*
 Action: failed
 Status: 5.5.0
 Diagnostic-Code: smtp;504 Need Fully Qualified Address
```

the php script is a standard mailto() with no frills, no headers or anything.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of the error given "Need Fully Qualified Address", you are not passing a proper email address.

My suggestion is to verify you using a qualified address for both the recipient and the sender.

However, 504 error message usually means you have improperly command in the SMTP communication (which has to do with the internal protocols).

It would be helpful to see the entire code to be able to identify if this is protocol issue, or a parameter issue.